# Why is a quote in parameter of Pipe automatically added?

Tags: swift, terminal, process, arguments, pipe

I have a strange problem:
When using a command in terminal, everything works fine. When using Pipe command with same parameters, system is failing because of quotes. This is the wrapper function I use for running a command (which works for years):

```
// delivers result of command => no redirection of output needed!
func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String]) -> String
{
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = launchPath
    task.arguments  = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe   // NEW 11.08.2020
    
    do {
        try task.run()
        // task.launch() till 10.12, but now catchable!
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return ""
    }
    
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    return output
}
```

Using this in terminal works fine:

```
/Users/dirk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DSPhotoStructureCleaner-awiixodrflmeajgbqdlklycdiewu/Build/Products/Debug/ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 '/Users/Shared/MeinDesktop/_Import Fotos/Test/_ORG/IMG_356308_2024.02.11-20.11.07_EOS5D4.MOV'
```

It returns:

```
mjpeg
```

Using complete path of ffprobe as launchPath, and the remaining for one argument, the output is:

```
"ffprobe version N-111833-gb5273c619d-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) ...  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100\nMissing argument for option \'v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 \'/Users/Shared/MeinDesktop/_Import Fotos/Test/_ORG/IMG_356308_2024.02.11-20.11.07_EOS5D4.MOV\'\'\n"
```

I don't know, where this last additional \' is coming from! And without single quotes command will fail because of spaces in the file path.

Comment: *“...  and the remaining for one argument ...”* that is the problem. You must pass each argument separately to the Task. The shell has its own mechanisms to split the command line into arguments, but `Task` does not do that.

Comment: OK, great tip. That was the reason! And no spaces in arguments, each parameter is a separate argument!

Comment: Glad to help! – I strongly assume that this has been asked and answered before on this site, but I haven't found it yet. I will check it later, and perhaps write an answer if I cannot find anything.